# How can I combine a dockerized python application and an existing SQLite database?

Tags: sqlite, docker

Okay, So I have a multiscript python application that creates an empty SQLite database, webscrapes data, and inserts it into the database. It also uses Spatialite to add geoms, so that created some issue when running the application on different computer platforms, specifically Windows.

So, I used docker to 'dockerize' the application. This worked well, and allows the application to run on different platforms.

Unfortunately, the webscrape takes a long time, so the application also has the function to only scrape and add new data to an existing SQLite database. That way it's much faster.

I'm still new to docker...
But, I don't think I can add a 1.2 GB SQLite db to a docker build.

I've seen some stuff about using $ docker cp to copy the sqlite database out of the container or mounting the container to the db in a local folder...

My overall goal is to have a page where interested parties can download an existing sqlite database, and have them be able to apply the dockerized python application to their downloaded database to add new data as it becomes available.

Does anyone know an easy and efficient way to do this?

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.6-stretch

COPY website.py /tmp
COPY json_data.py /tmp
COPY database.py /tmp
COPY update_whalealert.py /tmp
COPY update_spotter.py /tmp
COPY credentials.config /tmp/
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
COPY spotter.sqlite /tmp/

RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3-dev gcc libsqlite3-        
mod-spatialite

WORKDIR /tmp
CMD ["python", "update_whalealert.py"]
CMD ["python", "update_spotter.py"]
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get it to work by building the dockerfile with the whole sqlite database into the image, then run it, and when it's finished, use $ docker cp to copy the updated database into a local folder.

However, I'm still open to optimized methods.